# How can I change the name of i18n function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization

I have a simple express app which uses i18n for localization:

```
const express = require('express');
const i18n = require('i18n');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

i18n.configure({
    directory: path.join(__dirname, 'locales'),
    locales: ['en', 'de', 'it'],
    defaultLocale: 'en'
});

app.get('/:language?', (req, res) => {
    if (req.params.language) {
        i18n.setLocale(req.params.language);
    }

    res.send(i18n.__('Thank you for your support'));
});
```

and now I would like to change the way how I call the translation, so I don't have to type i18n every time. I thought I would do something like this:

```
const __ = i18n.__
```

and then call it like this:

```
__("Thank you for your support")
```

However, that doesn't work.
Could you please explain why and what is the solution for that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many other questions that are essentially duplicates, but they're hard to find if you don't know that up front. The trick is to use `.bind()` — `const __ = i18n.__.bind(i18n);`